# Host static website with GitLab pages

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I need to host a static website with gitlab pages. My repo is a private repository (or project) and the `.gitlab-ci.yml` that I tried to use looks like this:

```
image: gpecchio:BeCall
pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - echo 'Nothing to do...'
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - private
  only:
  - master
```

I believe that the `image` is wrong but I have no idea about what to change it to. I did some research but there aren't that many tutorials online for GitLab pages. How could I change this file to make it work?

**Other info that might be useful:** 
GitLab username: gpecchio 
GitLab project name: BeCall 
GitLab project url: https://gitlab.com/gpecchio/BeCall

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Is your website created in html or are you using a static generator to create your website and then using gitlab pages to host it?

In the **.gitlab-ci.yml** file, the artifacts need to be public (even if your repository is private) for hosting your website using gitlab pages.

Here are some examples of what your **.gitlab-ci.yml** file needs to look like for hosting your site with gitlab pages.

**HTML**

```
pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - mkdir .public
  - cp -r * .public
  - mv .public public
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master
```

**Jekyll**

```
image: ruby:2.3

pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - gem install jekyll
  - jekyll build -d public/
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master
```

**Hexo**

```
image: node:4.2.2

pages:
  cache:
    paths:
    - node_modules/

  script:
  - npm install hexo-cli -g
  - npm install
  - hexo deploy
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master
```

You should check out https://gitlab.com/pages/ which has examples of static sites created using all the different static site generator and hosted using gitlab pages.

You can also find some Jekyll themes hosted on gitlab pages at https://gitlab.com/groups/jekyll-themes

Finally, the link to your gitlab project url: https://gitlab.com/gpecchio/BeCall is private.

Comment: One more thing: GitLab is not zipping your HTML; add this to "script": `- gzip --keep public/*.html` See https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-pages/merge_requests/25